# PySFTP installation don't work on ubuntu 20.04 with pip

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

when i try to install pysftp, i've this error and all solutions on internet don't work sadly

```
pip3 install pysftp
Collecting pysftp
  Using cached pysftp-0.2.9.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I try

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
pip3 install supertools
python3.10 -m pip install setuptools
apt install python-setuptools
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? How did you install Python 3.10 (system package or dead-snakes PPA)? Does `apt install python-setuptools` install `setuptools` for Python 3.10? May be it should be `apt install python3-setuptools`? `apt install python3.10-setuptools`?

Comment: Recommend using a venv. It'll come prepacked with what you need. `apt-get install python3.10-venv`, `python3.10 -m venv .venv`, `source .venv/bin/activate`